# Ahadmin disabled

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, dcom

I am trying to manage ahadmin on windows 2008 server:
component servivces (MMC snapin) -> Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config\ahadmin -> Properties

but, when the properties window gets opened everything is disabled.

I tried both a local and domain Administrator.

How to enable these properties?

Comment: Hm, seems like the all of the DCOM Config is locked. Also if I go to Services -> DCOM Process Server Launcher, I cn't edit any of its properties (they are disabled).

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/242714/how-can-i-enable-ahadmin-properties/242719#242719

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/242714/how-can-i-enable-ahadmin-properties/242719#242719) for an explanation of how to make the properties editable.

Answer (score 0):

The grayed out properties in Component Services is normal.

Have you enabled it in Server Manager -> Features?  What issue or error are you getting with AhAdmin?  Do appcmd and other IIS features work as expected?

Comment: Normal, yes, but that can be changed ;-) See my answer.

Comment: That's good to know.  Thanks for providing the update.