# How can I enable ahadmin properties?

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, dcom

I need to run dcomcnfg.exe on a Windows Server 2008 and in Component Services\Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config, select the “ahadmin” COM+ package and add a new Endpoint. Problem is that I can't do it; everything is greyed out, despite being logged in with an Administrator account.

Is there some windows feature that needs to be installed in order to be able to edit "ahadmin"? Is there some Role I need to add to this user in order to do these changes? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/4a94acde-d7dc-496a-9ecf-c1eb04ed83ce/), the reason that the options in the configuration dialog are disable is that the corresponding registry is by default writeable only for TrustedInstaller to prevent admins from messing with it ;-)

To change this, open Regedit and navigate to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID{9fa5c497-f46d-447f-8011-05d03d7d7ddc}". First change the owner to "Administrators" and then give "Administrators" full control. After restarting DComCnfg you can edit the configuration of ahadmin.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help and sorry for the delay in validating the answer :)